# Vue.js app with plugins without a build process, how to do it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, cdn

I know one can develop vue.js application without build process, for example by including

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>`.

But what about plugins? Let's say I want to use `vue-good-table`, should I find a link for every minified javascript file for every plugin, and their dependencies too?

Is there an easy way to do it?

The reasons are explained [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html#standalone-script), I need to add functionality to existent web applications.

Comment: Not sure exactly how to write it exactly, but if the package works with Vue3 and is available here: https://www.skypack.dev/ you may maybe somehow make it work. Will not be simple IMO.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, but I have to manually find all packages, and I suppose all dependencies must be resolved manually.

Comment: I guess that the CDN will come with most of it, otherwise yep. x(

Answer (score 2):

`vue-good-table-next` (for Vue 3) has a ["global" build](https://unpkg.com/vue-good-table-next@0.1.0/dist/vue-good-table-next.global.prod.js) that works via CDN, but it expects `window.vue` to already be defined, so you'd have to import `vue` first (which defines `window.Vue`), and assign a global `vue` to `Vue`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.33/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
  // workaround: VueGoodTable expects 'vue' to be defined
  window.vue = window.Vue;
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-good-table-next@0.1.0/dist/vue-good-table-next.global.prod.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/vue-good-table-next@0.1.0/dist/vue-good-table-next.css"
/>
```

Then, `VueGoodTable.default` is defined as the `vue-good-table` plugin, which can be installed on the app instance via [`app.use()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use):

```html
<div id="app">
  <vue-good-table ⋯></vue-good-table>
</div>

<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({⋯})
app.use(VueGoodTable.default)
app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-good-table-next?file=index.html)